# Reworking a constructor in a subclass

Tags: java, oop, constructor, super

I have the following problem with constructors. I'm trying to rewrite the function for `Cel` which is a subclass of `GameObject` (`GameObject` needs `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` and an `id`). I wanted to add `xPosGrid` and `yPosGrid` to make sure I know where all the Cels are in the Grid. But I didn't want to make the constructor extremely long. So I wanted to use a second constructor (down below).

But this gives me an error

> Implicit super constructor GameObject() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Can anyone tell me how to get around this problem. It would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Constructor that does work
public Cel(int x, int y, int width, int height, ID id) {
    super(x, y, width, height, id);
}

//Constructor that doesn't work
public Cel(int xPosGrid, int yPosGrid, Grid grid, ID id) {

    x = grid.x + grid.celWidth * xPosGrid;
    y = grid.y + grid.celHeight * yPosGrid;
    width = grid.celWidth;
    height = grid.celHeight;
    this.id = id;
    this.xPosGrid = xPosGrid;
    this.yPosGrid = yPosGrid;
}

//GameObject Constructor
public GameObject(int x, int y, int width, int height, ID id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the difference between x and xPosGrid?

Comment: You are not forced to do everything in the constructor of your class: create a `SetGridPosition` method to update `xPosGrid` and `yPosGrid` (you can default them to 0.0 in the constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `GameObject` does not define an empty constructor. If you omit a call to `super`, Java implicitly adds `super()` as the first statement of the child constructor.

Solutions: either add an empty constructor to `GameObject` (making it `protected` t avoid surprises) or call `this` or `super` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks that really helped ^-^

Comment: You are welcome. Please, don't forget to select an answer (checkmark on the left) to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to call the super constructor first in a constructor.

```
public Cel(int x, int y, int width, int height, ID id) {
    super(x, y, width, height, id);
}

public Cel(int xPosGrid, int yPosGrid, Grid grid, ID id) {
    super(0,0,0,0,id);
    x = grid.x + grid.celWidth * xPosGrid;
    y = grid.y + grid.celHeight * yPosGrid;
    width = grid.celWidth;
    height = grid.celHeight;
    this.id = id;
    this.xPosGrid = xPosGrid;
    this.yPosGrid = yPosGrid;
}
```

If you can set the x and y and width and height later you modify it

```
public Cel(int xPosGrid, int yPosGrid, Grid grid, ID id) {
    super(0,0,0,0,id);
    x = grid.x + grid.celWidth * xPosGrid;
    y = grid.y + grid.celHeight * yPosGrid;
    width = grid.celWidth;
    height = grid.celHeight;
    this.id = id;
    this.xPosGrid = xPosGrid;
    this.yPosGrid = yPosGrid;

    // do some calculations to caluclate the pos and dimensions.

    this.setX(x);
    this.setY(y);
    this.setWidth(width);
    this.setHeight(height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not call `super(...)` or `this(...)` the compiler adds `super()`. As the error tells you: there is no super-constructor without parameters. So you need to add this constructor or invoke the existing super-construcor with dummy-values.

Answer (score 0):

You are **mistaken**. You can't have two constructors and call them **both** for the same object.

When you write `new Cel()` ... then you have to give the parameters that matches **one** of your consturctors exactly.

You can't come in later on and call that other constructor. In that sense: understand what the essential properties of your subclass are, and then provide **one** constructor to fit that model.